# Font color in Ti.UI.createPicker

Tags: fonts, colors, appcelerator, dropdown, appcelerator-titanium

I tried to set the font color to black and I can't, I would appreciate your help with this:

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor : "#ffffff",
  exitOnClose: true,
  layout: 'vertical'
});

var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    borderWidth : 1,
    borderColor : "gray",
    color : "black",
    borderRadius : 5,
    width : "90%",
  top:50
});

var data = [];
data[0]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'El Salvador'});
data[1]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Guatemala'});
data[2]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Honduras'});
data[3]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Nicaragua'});
data[4]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Costa Rica'});

picker.add(data);
picker.selectionIndicator = true;

win.add(picker);
win.open();
```

// must be after picker has been displayed
picker.setSelectedRow(0, 2, false);

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Label` tag inside  `PickerRow`

```
<Picker  >
         <PickerColumn id="column1">
              <PickerRow   >
                <Label   color="#0000"    > Blah Blah </Label>
              </PickerRow>
             </PickerColumn> 

</Picker>
```

Comment: Excuse me, I am a noobie, I see that code like alloy code, isn't it? Or... Where inside the PickerRow?

Comment: Yes , it`s Alloy code , but you can easily write this code into Classic!

Comment: I can do that, but I want to change the font color of the textbox and your solution is for picker row

Comment: I did this, but didn't worked:                                                                       var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
 hintText : "Ëscoja País",
 borderWidth : 1,
 borderColor : "gray",
 color : "black",
 borderRadius : 5,
 width : "90%",
  top:50
});

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  text: 'Escoja País',
  font: { fontColor: "gray" } 
});

Comment: @jdponce `font.fontColor` is not a valid property. It is just `color`.

Answer (score 2):

Create themes.xml in /platform/android/res/values/themes.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="LightTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
   <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItem</item>
</style>

<style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:background">#d0d0d0</item>
</style>
<style name="mySpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks Venkatesh, and after that... how can I do in order to apply those theme in my app? The app is for iOS and Android

Comment: This is only for Android. In your AndroidManifest.xml or tiapp.xml. You have mention the theme name "LightTheme" in the application Tag
`<application android:largeHeap="true" android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="XXXXX" android:name="XXXXX" android:theme="@style/LightTheme">`

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to implement the enhancements that came out as part of 5.2, the docs say you can only change the color if the picker is a type of time or datetime. https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-16547

But Abada's method of using the label works fine.